# I am getting exception "resource busy and acquire with NOWAIT specified or timeout expired" when creating Index

Tags: oracle, plsql, cursor

I have tables A and B. First due to some codelevel things I dropped certain indexes of table A. After that I run the script below: (I am providing only the general idea of it.)

```
Decalre

cursor SOME is select a.something from A a, B b where a.id=b.id;

Begin

open SOME;
loop

fetch something;
exit when count= 0;

loop
begin
   some update statement on table A;

  commit;
    continue;
   end;
    end loop;
   end loop;
commit;
   close SOME;
end;
```

The problem is that when I try to create index for table A I get error `resource busy and acquire with NOWAIT specified or timeout expired`

I am using Oracle 12c.

Comment: update is success, but the table A is not accessible in the next script.

Comment: is your loop finishing?
is the when condition count = 0 satisfied at a point before  you create the index?

Comment: @micklesh yes. loop will finish this is just number of rows pending with that crieteria.